# Easy function to get column means from a factorized dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, filter

I'm trying to make a function that firstly make groups based on a given factor (which is the second column) and then provides the column means of those groups. 
How could I create a new dataframe including only the column means of those groups?

These commands works separately, but I'm having troubles to come with the right syntax, for creating the new dataframe.

```
get_means <- function(df, factor){

    for (i in fixed_list){

    filter(df, factor == i) -> df_i
    colMeans(df_1[,-c(1:2)])
    rbind(df_i) -> means_df
   }

return (means_df)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are already functions available to do what you're describing. For example...

```
df <- data.frame(factor = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), y1 = rnorm(9), y2 = rnorm(9))

require(dplyr)
(result <- summarise(group_by(df, factor), meanY1 = mean(y1), meanY2 = mean(y2)))
data.frame(result)
```

Comment: or with base R's aggregate: `aggregate(.~factor, data=df, mean)`.